# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7. xcode 10. ionic ios project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, ionic3

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentType", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentContainer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am getting this linker error when I am trying to build my iOS project.
I have created this project using ionic 3. 
I have installed pods.

Answer (score 1):

The FIRComponent symbol was introduced in the Firebase 5.5.0 release with a definition in the FirebaseCore pod and reference in the FirebaseAuth pod.

Make sure you have at least version 5.1.0 of the FirebaseCore pod installed.